# Tailwind intellisens isn't working with cdn

Tags: visual-studio-code, cdn

Tailwind intellisens doesn't work in VScode while using tailwind with cdn. Doesn't show suggestions.

I tried reinstalling intellisens and I tried npm tailwind installation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this type `npx tailwindcss init` command in the terminal. You can see that Config.tailwind.js file will appear now in filelist and you will be able to see suggestions while writing the code.